# How to search stored data item in sql server according to input value and display in DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to search stored sql server table data using text box and according to its given input and want to show it to a DataGridView. Need help to solve this issue.

```
private void ViewSearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-FQBMN3R\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB; Integrated Security=true");

        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_student_info where name like '%' + @search + ''%' ", connection);
       xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ViewTextBox.Text;
        connection.Open();
        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = xp;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "name");
        ViewDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        connection.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parameterised query

```
string sql = "SELECT * from Test WHERE User_FirstName=@User_FirstName, User_LastName=@User_LastName";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql , _connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_FirstName", FirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_LastName", LastName.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked for me perfectly

Comment: No problem. Can you accept it as the answer.

Comment: yeah...of course